# How to create sub-domain after register with primary domain by user?

Tags: php, codeigniter, subdomain

I am using CodeIgniter framework with PHP and I'm working on a project that provide to visitor register our shop my site with a sub-domain of my company website, for example http://www.shopify.com/ is website. then after registration this provide a domain to access our website to our visitor like http://myksb.myshopify.com/ or www.myksb.shopify.com

Here shopify.com is main website domain name, and myksb is customer shop name.

Finally we can register our shop on this website with desired subdomain.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to setup a Wildcard DNS record, you can check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record) wikipedia article for more details on what that means.

You can also read [this thread](http://forums.cpanel.net/f34/how-make-wildcard-subdomains-61990.html) on the cPanel forum on how to set this up.

After that you will need in your application logic to parse the request URL, to extract the subdomain and to validate it against a valid username.